# If i use a separated ASP.NET Membership database how should i handle the relations to the user tables?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

If i use a separated ASP.NET Membership database what is the correct way to define the relations between the user tables and application data tables?. Should i create copies of the user tables and sync? or is ok to just create the Guid columns and enforce validation in the application code?, Are there any issues with performance that i should be aware of when separating databases?

Answer (score 0):

You can Create two database , one for Membership control and other for Web-site use.
I have Many sites which are running on same concept. No need to worry. web-site will be fast and secure.

If you want to learn more on this or want a live demo then download a classified starter kit for asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Just make the join on databases(with double dots) when you need data.
No need to change, just handle the userid, role etc but need to create two different connection string in your app.
OR Copy the tables in your original db